Error: Connection refused, errno = 111 on flutter project
iam having a problem in my project when iam trying to login in the app with the database it says
"Unhandled Exception: SocketException: Connection refused (OS Error: Connection refused, errno = 111), address = localhost, port = 41286" i have my database in mysql and i coonect to it in mysql.dart  . can someone help me with that.
import 'package:mysql1/mysql1.dart';

class Mysql {
  static String host = 'localhost',
      user = 'root',
      password = 'abdo2002@1967',
      db = 'college';
  static int port = 3306;

  Mysql();

  Future<MySqlConnection> getConnection() async {
    var settings = ConnectionSettings(
        host: host, port: port, user: user, password: password, db: db);
    return await MySqlConnection.connect(settings);
  }
}

i tryied to turn off the firewall i was thinking maybe some rule is preventing this or  its the user priviliage i checked everything and i still don,t know how to solve it

Please don't post code as an image, edit your question and add code
